# RxJavaSwing + MVVM with Portrait Landscape Views

Tags: java, swing, mvvm, rx-java

In my Java desktop project using, [RxJavaSwing] https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaSwing,

[RxJava3] https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava, following MVVM architecture given by Petikoch examples https://github.com/Petikoch/Java_MVVM_with_Swing_and_RxJava_Examples able to implement socket programming based application easily.

Now I want to implement this for landscape and portrait modes. Is there a way to implement this something like below image. If so,

1) How to pass 2 different view instances to ViewModel (dynamically when the orientation changes).

2) Also I pass the view object to UsecaseImpl for panel replacement. Here also I need to pass 2 different views now.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Code:

```
View view = new View();
UsecaseImpl useCaseImpl = new UseCaseImpl(view, defaultValues);
ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
Model model = new Model(useCaseImpl);
viewModel.connectTo(model);        
view.bind(viewModel);    <br>
```

Also how to implement below code in MVVM based on an event from UsecaseImpl(currently it is in Util common for all views)

```
public static void switchChildPanel(JPanel jPanelParent, JPanel jPanelChild) {
    if(jPanelChild.isShowing()) {
        return;
    }
    jPanelParent.removeAll();
    jPanelParent.add(jPanelChild);
    jPanelParent.repaint();
    jPanelParent.invalidate();
    jPanelChild.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im able to solve this by creating and passing 2 views and binding them with ViewModel. Only views are different instances and rest of them are same.

```
PortraitView portraitView = new PortraitView();
LandscapeView landscapeView = new LandscapeView();
UsecaseImpl useCaseImpl = new UseCaseImpl(portraitView, landscapeView, defaultValues);
ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
Model model = new Model(useCaseImpl);
viewModel.connectTo(model);        
portairView.bind(viewModel);
landscapeView.bind(viewModel);
```

`switchChildPanel(JPanel jPanelParent, JPanel jPanelChild)` now I can access this code in Util related to its view from usecaseImpl. So it remains as it is without any changes. Rest of the UI components are updated as per MVVM flow.